# Когда задаю margin - top то фоновый цвет двигается вместе с текстом. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы фон не двигался вместе с текстом

Tags: html, css

```
<article>
    <div class="the_main_inf">
      <div class="the_main_inf1">  
        <p>Sell Your House Instantly</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>



.the_main_inf1{
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 236px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Фоновый цвет у какого элемента? 
Вероятно, вы задаете background кому-то из родительских элементов и двигаете блок, растягивая родительский элемент.

В следующий раз или лучше формулируйте мысль или вставляйте полный код, чтобы можно было понять суть)